# Logstash pipeline "in" clause

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack

Quick background:

- We're using filebeats to add fields to messages - a 'pipeline_marker' and a 'service' marker.
- Ideally, they will go into a index called `foo-${[fields][service]}-${+YYYY.MM.dd}`

However we are worried that 'some' servers might be misconfigured and not have these markers (we have automation to protect us, but we're all about the belt-and-bracer approach).

The Logstash documentation is at best vague, and sometimes wrong, e.g. the use of quote marks or not around certain elements. But this is what we have:

```
- pipeline.id beats-server
  config.string |
      input { beats { port => 5504 }}
      output {
        if [fields][pipeline_marker] == "application" {     # works
            pipeline { send_to => "application" }
        } else if [fields][pipeline_marker] == "REDACTED" { # works
            pipeline { send_to => "REDACTED" }
        } else if [service] in [fields] {                   # THIS DOESNT 
            pipeline { send_to => "default-service" }
        } else {                                            # Works
            pipeline { send_to => "default"
        }
      }
```

and then the pipeline configs, which are all good.

So specifically the statement `if [service] in [fields]`. I've tried some alternatives of `if "service" in [fields]` - the Logstash docs say 'in' is a thing, and I found one vague example. Basically everything falls through to my default catch-everything index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `if [service] in [fields]` you are testing if the value of the field `service` is in the value of the field `fields`, but `fields` does not have any value in the top level, it has nested fields, like the ones you tested before, for example `[fields][pipeline_marker]`.

If you want to test if `[fields][service]` exists, you should use:

```
if [fields][service] { }
```

Or if you want to test against it you should use `if [something] in [fields][service]`

Comment: Thank you, I think my python part of my brain kicked in and I was trying to do the equivalent of `if foo in some_list`.